# Printing names of pairs of cities where the first city's population is less than the other

Tags: sql

Let's say we have **one** table City with the following fields.

**CITY**

ID....................int

Name.............char(20)

Population.......int

```
ID | Name | Population
1  | Tokyo | 200
2  | Houston | 300
3  | Manchester | 100
```

How do you query pairs of cities where first city's population is less than the second city and separated with a space? (population of name A < population of name B)

Expected result:

```
Manchester, Tokyo
Tokyo, Houston
```

I tried the following:

```
SELECT a.name, b.name
FROM CITY a,
     CITY b
WHERE a.population < b.population AND a.population != b.population;
```

Comment: Why not `Manchester, Houston`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, presumably you need to concatenate the city *names* together.  You are fetching the populations.

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', a.name, b.name)
FROM CITY a JOIN
     CITY b 
     ON a.population < b.population;
```

`CONCAT_WS()` is a convenient function that concatenates values with a separator.

This condition is unnecessary: `AND a.population != b.population`